# How to get a Flux from a Mono flatmap?

Tags: spring, reactor

I have the following code:

```
public Flux<Foo> getFoos(String xyz) {
    return getBar(xyz).flatMap(b -> Flux.empty()));
}
```

But it results in a compilation error because `getBars()` returns a `Mono<Bar>` instead of a `Flux<Bar>`. How can I return a Flux from a `flatMap()` of a Mono value? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution. I just had to use `flatMapMany()` instead of `flatMap()`